# okhttp3 FLOW_CONTROL_ERROR

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, socket-timeout-exception

I am uploading `.mp4` video using [Retrofit 2.1.0](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) and [OKHTTP 3.6.0](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). On some videos, I am having this exception. The timeout is set to 30 sec.

```
okhttp3.internal.http2.StreamResetException: stream was reset: FLOW_CONTROL_ERROR
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.checkOutNotClosed(Http2Stream.java:567)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$FramingSink.emitFrame(Http2Stream.java:501)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$FramingSink.write(Http2Stream.java:481)
W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:171)
W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:91)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?